# why I am not able to code and edit code in android studio in activity_main xml file?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In Android Studio

when I click on any line in the source code, the lines get highlighted but the caret indicator is not showing and the code is not editable

[As you can see in text View  the "id" is highlighted but the code is not editable][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmi5Z.png

Would someone tell me how can I make it right?

> > > > Solutions:

first of all, thanks everyone for trying helping me with this problem

> > So after wasting almost 5 hours here are some methods I used and solved my problem

1: File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and restart
2: Delete the android studio project folder in user folder in C drive
3: Click on the right side of android studio and then try to code
4: Click on the " green V " and disable  "Idea Vim"
5: Delete unwanted plugins
6: Reinstall Android studio

For me, method 4 worked but here I mentioned all of them, just in case; It might not work for others.

Comment: Show to code or screenshot of the problem

Comment: I have already tried (file > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and restart ) but nothing happened.

Comment: Edit your question and add the screenshot of your problem

Comment: I edited the question. please take a look and I am sorry but I don't know how I can upload the screen shot.. as I am a new user, joined today only.

Comment: In your Edit question portion you might be having a gallery icon click on it and it will redirect you to the file structure get your screen shot from there and save your question here so that we might help you.

Comment: Kindly take a look ..on screenshot I added  with the question (. stack overflow added a URL instead of the screenshot) I shared,

Comment: try running android studio as an administrator, if that doesn't work, clean your project, exit android studio , open task manager, and kill android studio if it's still open and your JDK framework (or just reboot the pc)

Comment: new development: When I am pressing "x" on any letter it is acting like "backspace" but I still can't write anything. So I tried using a different keyboard but same story.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot I think you are in an Insert mode

click on INS button top of arrow keys

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods to solve this problem:

1: File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and restart.
2: Delete the android studio project folder in user folder in C drive.
3: Click on the right side of android studio and then try to code.
4: Click on the "green V" bottom-right corner and disable "Idea Vim."
5: Delete unwanted plugins.
6: Reinstall Android studio.

For me, method 4 worked.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "green V" bottom-right corner and disable "Idea Vim."